# Privacy Policy refuses my application on Google Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I have a very big problem with google play console who refuses to accept my app :
Status: App not available on Google Play

I’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that your app, Sade, (com.appdating.sade), still violates Google Play Policy. I’ve included details below about the specific issue with your app and what you can do to get your app back on Google Play.

Step 1: Review the policy violation with your app

We found that your app is not compliant with the SMS and Call Log Permissions policy, or we were unable to review and verify your in-app experience for compliance with this policy.

The problem is that i need to have the sms autorisation because of this functionnality on my app, so this is my answer :

I understand that our application is not compliant with the SMS and Call Log Permissions policy, but among the links you have shared :
Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups
We found the case of an exception which is : Physical Security/SMS Emergency Alerts , Apps that send SMS alerts in case of emergency. That's why we have choose in play console > Rules and programs > Application content > SMS and call log permissions , this denomination because we are not a sms manager but an app of dating, we understand that. So, what can we do ? Our service Dating is just about security for people who are in danger and we are in the case of the exception of your policies. We can't do anything else, we sincerely understand that we are not conform to your policies but we ask you an exception to use SMS_SEND for the security of our users.

But there is no amelioration and google still refuses my app....

Can you help me please ?

Its been days i turn in round because google play console didn't help me more

I have send us a lot of emails explaining why i need sms but no answer

Answer (score -1):

If your app can't send SMS, do you have the possibility to use any company or private phone to send the SMS instead?

If affirmative, send the messages you would like to send directly, to a database and the other phone looks for these messages and sends them on their behalf. Or use a paid service which does this kind of notification.